# (Android) How to Save activity Data (Listview)when start new activity and restart again main activity listview activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I am new in Android development. I want to develop a questionnaire. There are only two activities in questionnaire Main activity and camera activity. in May Main activity I have `ListView`  with `ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE`.+ two text field for latitude and longitude. when user give Right question i checked check box grammatically. When all Question Checked then User can capture photo so i start Camera activity on button click like this

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(myContext,MyCAMERA.class);
startActivity(cameraIntent);
```

When User Confirm Photo i start Main activity gain as follow

```
Intent mainIntent = new Intent(this, MAINActivity.class);

startActivity(mainIntent);
```

When I start back main  activity as mention above my all checkbox are unchecked (have lost data) text fields are clear. How Can i saved these data in original state when go back from camera activity My code are as follow

Main activity

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.titlebar);
irisContext = this;
mHandler = new Handler();
getGUIFromXMLDoc();
.
.
.
. so on
```

all other button click function called in `getGUIFromXMLDoc()` function etc

sorry for my poor English. I hope you can understand my question

i have already look at some similar question on this blog but not any relevant answer or not clearly explained

please help me as soon as possible

Answer (score 3):

start your Camera Activity like this way

```
Intent mainIntent = new Intent(this, MAINActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(mainIntent);
```

it will start the camera activity as child don't start new activity from camera when you complete camera activity finish this way

```
setResult(RESULT_OK);
finish();
```

of if cancel from that activity then do like this

```
setResult(RESULT_CANCEL);
finish();
```

now it will finish the camera activity and go back to the main activity

Comment: if you getting useful answer then vote up and getting exact/nearest solution from any answer you should accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can save activity state in the callback method onSaveInstanceState() in your MainActivity. 
When you'll back to this activity next time, you may retrieve data from Bundle in onCreate() method.

Another way is to start MyCamera activity with startActivityForResult(), and after MyCamera activity is done, set result value and finish it.